# No match when searching a (Docker) Server using ldapjs

Tags: node.js, docker, ldap, ldapjs

I have an Ldap Server running on Docker + ldapjs. This server is adding a set of records that I am trying to search for with the client.
A sample user object looks like below:

```
    {
        user: 'cn=first.last,ou=user_group,o=main',
        info: {
            cn: 'first.last',
            email: 'first.last@mail.com'
        }
    }
```

The options would look like this:

```
      let opts = {
            scope: 'base',
            attributes: ['dn', 'sn', 'cn', 'user', 'info']
        };
```

I'm using this code in a class, so I bind in the constructor, after initializing the client:

```
    constructor(url) {
        client = ldap.createClient({
            url: url
        });
        client.on('error', (err) => {
            log.error(`${err}`);
        });
        client.bind(username, password, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                log.error(`${err}`);
            }
        });
        log.info('Client Initialized.');
    };
```

And my search code:

```
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var record = {};
                client.search(username, opts, function (err, res) {
                    res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
                        log.info(`Record Retrieved: ${JSON.stringify(entry.object)}`);
                        record = entry.object;
                    });
                    res.on('error', function (err) {
                        log.error(`Error: ${err.message}`);
                    });
                    res.on('end', function (result) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            log.info(`Status: ${result.status}`);
                            resolve(record);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that the code will always resolve on end when I make a search request from the client, which means that I never get a match, although it's definitely there.

I've tried:

- Binding inside and outside the promise instead. No difference.
- Changing the user structure and username used in client.search. No difference.
- Searching for only 'cn=first'. I do get an error that it doesn't exist, which is good.
- Adding a filter in options and changing the parameters there, but still no result.

I connect to the server ok, bind is ok as well, so I think I'm either doing the search wrong, or the way I have structured the users in the server is not proper.

Added screenshot showing server logs: The user added in the entry looks like it has a different name, but I changed it to match in the data.
[image]

Comment: @madkimachi Show us Dockerfile.

Comment: Also docker ps output,is there ldap container?

Comment: @RichardRublev Ldap Container is running ok and is reachable. I get the proper response when I search for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @RichardRublev added a screenshot. You may not the cn is different than one I described, but that's already been changed to match the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, which was related to the structure I was using in my records, I've solved it using an ldapts client instead, but the same logic can be used in an ldapjs client:

Specifically:
This is a record in my ldapjs Server:

```
{
 name: 'John Doe',
 uid: 'john.doe',
 dn: 'uid=john.doe, ou=users, o=server',
 email: 'john.doe@email.com',
 userprincipalname: 'cgi-doej',
}
```

This is how I search for it:

```
let attributes = ['cn'], filter = `(email=${email})`

const { searchEntries, searchReferences } = await this.client.search(searchDN, {
 scope: 'base',
 filter: filter,
 attributes: attributes
});
```

This has solved my issues.